# Not able to open excel in Standalone cluster in wildfly 13

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, jboss, zk

We are trying to setup standalone cluster on wildfly 13 and cluster is working perfectly fine except one feature which is displaying the excel in our web application. We are using Zk framework to show excel. The problem which we are facing is that the excel is perfectly fine when we are working on a single machine but as soon as we introduce another server in the cluster. We get session Time out on Zk. The current pom.xml , zk.xml and jboss-web.xml and web.xml I am attaching and the issue which I am facing is also I am attaching. Please provide any useful feedback for the problem.

```
        <commons-io>2.4</commons-io>
                ....
            <id>ZK CE</id>
            <name>ZK CE Repository</name>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ZK EVAL</id>
            <name>ZK Evaluation Repository</name>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/eval</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>zkmaven</id>
            <name>ZK Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zss</groupId>
            <artifactId>zss</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkbind</artifactId>
            <version>${zk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zul</artifactId>
            <version>${zk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkplus</artifactId>
            <version>${zk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zhtml</artifactId>
            <version>${zk.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

zk.xml

```
<system-config>
        <ui-factory-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableUiFactory</ui-factory-class>
        <disable-zscript>true</disable-zscript>
    </system-config>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>speadsheet</context-root> 
    <replication-config>
        <replication-granularity>SESSION</replication-granularity>
    </replication-config>
    <max-active-sessions>5</max-active-sessions>
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml contains  tag

```
Exception which I am getting is : 

[org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow] (default task-4) javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException
    at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan.InfinispanBatch.close(InfinispanBatch.java:102)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSession.requestDone(DistributableSession.java:91)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.updateSessionAccessTime(ServletContextImpl.java:945)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:579)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:339)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException
    at org.infinispan.commons@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl.finishResource(TransactionImpl.java:451)
    at org.infinispan.commons@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl.commitResources(TransactionImpl.java:466)
    at org.infinispan.commons@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl.runCommit(TransactionImpl.java:335)
    at org.infinispan.commons@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:110)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan.InfinispanBatch.close(InfinispanBatch.java:97)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
    at org.infinispan@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionCoordinator.handleCommitFailure(TransactionCoordinator.java:211)
    at org.infinispan@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionCoordinator.commit(TransactionCoordinator.java:157)
    at org.infinispan@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.transaction.xa.XaTransactionTable.commit(XaTransactionTable.java:122)
    at org.infinispan@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.transaction.xa.TransactionXaAdapter.commit(TransactionXaAdapter.java:68)
    at org.infinispan.commons@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl.finishResource(TransactionImpl.java:419)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSerializableException: org.zkoss.zss.ui.impl.ua.ApplyBorderHandler
    Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSerializableException: org.zkoss.zss.ui.impl.ua.ApplyBorderHandler
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2022)
        at org.infinispan@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.await(CompletableFutures.java:82)
        at org.infinispan@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.SimpleAsyncInvocationStage.get(SimpleAsyncInvocationStage.java:37)
        at org.infinispan@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.invoke(AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.java:250)
        at org.infinispan@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:137)
        at org.infinispan@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionCoordinator.commit(TransactionCoordinator.java:155)
        at org.infinispan@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.transaction.xa.XaTransactionTable.commit(XaTransactionTable.java:122)
        at org.infinispan@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.transaction.xa.TransactionXaAdapter.commit(TransactionXaAdapter.java:68)
        at org.infinispan.commons@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl.finishResource(TransactionImpl.java:419)
        at org.infinispan.commons@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl.commitResources(TransactionImpl.java:466)
        at org.infinispan.commons@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl.runCommit(TransactionImpl.java:335)
        at org.infinispan.commons@9.2.4.Final//org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:110)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan.InfinispanBatch.close(InfinispanBatch.java:97)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSession.requestDone(DistributableSession.java:91)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.updateSessionAccessTime(ServletContextImpl.java:945)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:579)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:339)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@13.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.9.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSerializableException: org.zkoss.zss.ui.impl.ua.ApplyBorderHandler]
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in object org.zkoss.zss.ui.impl.ua.ApplyBorderHandler@a8433b0
    in object java.util.LinkedList@a8433cf
    in field org.zkoss.zss.ui.impl.DefaultUserActionManagerCtrl._handlerMap
    in object org.zkoss.zss.ui.impl.DefaultUserActionManagerCtrl@13283bef
    in field org.zkoss.zss.ui.Spreadsheet._actionManagerCtrl
    in object org.zkoss.zss.ui.Spreadsheet@61d66635
    in object org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.PageImpl@434df628
    in field org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl._pages
    in object org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl@954df9e
    in field org.zkoss.util.CacheMap$Value.value
    in object org.zkoss.util.CacheMap$Value@6fad9a0b
    in object org.zkoss.util.CacheMap$Value@6fad9a0b
    in field org.zkoss.util.CacheMap._map
    in object org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache$Cache@694ebc95
    in field org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache._desktops
    in object org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache@3b2548c9
    in object org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession@27ba9dfa
    in object java.util.HashMap@7cbe8d74
```